# How to find both files and folders that are used in some process?

Tags: linux

I want to delete files and folders older than 15 days.

But Before deletion I want to check that those file and folders shouldn't use anywhere. How can i do that ?

is ps -ef works for this ?

Comment: You can use the `find` command for that. Take a look at its "man page": `man find` That explains all the options available.

Comment: [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the find command:

```
find /path/to/folder -type f -mtime +15 -delete
```

Comment: `find /path/to/folder -type f -mtime +15 -delete -o -type d -mtime +15 -exec rmdir {} \;` does everything in one command.